# Ubuntu 18 dash icons on multiple monitors group all windows instead of just the ones for the monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

On Ubuntu 18, when using multiple monitors, if I have a say a chrome window open on both monitors the dash on both monitors will show two windows open and it doesn't matter on which monitor I click the dash it will always handle both windows.

This is very inconvenient for me and I would like to change it so that the dash window grouping is separate for each monitor (I think Ubuntu 16 behaved this way by default). How can I do this?